# Update textbox for each row in gridview on One Button Click

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, gridviewrow

In my gridview I have given a textbox for each row which has a corresponding button which fetches the value from the textbox and updates that rows value in the database.

But I want to add one button on top in the Header Template which will fetch the value of all textboxes and update their rows.

I have tried the following code but I get a null reference exception at the "instance_id cell[0]"

My code is below.

`

```
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:ButtonField Text="Update Attendance" CommandName="Select" />

            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>`
```

And on Button Click to fetch the data from all the textboxes:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        vo.instance_ID = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;

        vo.Project_ID = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;

        vo.volunteer_ID = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[6].Text;

        vo.Campus_ID = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[5].Text;

        vo.attendance_hours = (GridView1.SelectedRow.FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox).Text;

        Convert.ToInt32(vo.attendance_hours);

        try
        {
            int success = BL.fn_UpdateAttendance(vo);
            if (success == 2)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Attendance Updated Successfully')", true);
                // Label2.Text = "Attendance Updated Successfully";
            }
            else
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Attendance Not Updated')", true);
                //  Label2.Text = "Attendance Not Updated";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My friend suggested using row.Cells[0]; inside the foreach and it worked!

Thank you everyone.